# Google maps custom overlay with wrong width

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay, custom-overlay

I'm trying to make my custom overlay for google maps. I use this [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) example. And I have problem with overlay width definition.

```
var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

// Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
var div = this.div_;
div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
```

This code returns width less than one pixel for overlay with this latlonbox:

```
<LatLonBox>
<north>90.0</north>
<south>-90.0</south>
<east>180.0</east>
<west>-180.0</west>
</LatLonBox>
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? Maybe someone knows a solution. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems this happens when the bounds intersect the prime-meridian.

Try this to calculate the width:

```
         ((ne.x - sw.x)
          +
          (((ne.x - sw.x)<0
            ||
          this.bounds_.getNorthEast().lng()
          -
          this.bounds_.getSouthWest().lng()>=360)
            ? overlayProjection.getWorldWidth()
            : 0))
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4vj37ecy/

Comment: Oh, thanks it's work! But now I see the problem with height too. As I understand, in google maps longitude can take values [-85, 85].But google earth kml contains values -90 and 90. So height and top walues are wrong too. How I can fix that?
Demo: http://iwep.wc.lt/ (overlay seen with minimal zoom level)